# How to get site settings from class that derived from RouteBase class

Tags: orchardcms

MyRoute class is created by IRouteProvider. I need to manage routes depending on some settings. This settings store in separate table and i have two options to get them.

First. Get settings from site content `workContext.CurrentSite.As<MySettings>()` that uses IRepository to get them
But in RouteBase.GetRouteData method `_workContextAccessor.GetContext()` always return null

Second. Get settings directly from my service `_myService.GetList()` that uses IRepository to get them
But `IRepository<T>.Table` property sometimes gives an error that connection to mssql does not set and site stops working

Comment: First, can you explain why you think your route needs to depend on a setting?

Comment: I am developing multilanguage website where different versions have different domain names. I am using Orchard.Localization module for it. I need that pages is displayed on same aliases but different domain names. Ex, alias stores in Orchard_Alias_AliasRecord as 'en-us/my-page' and i displays this page on en.domain.ru/my-page (for homepage alias is 'en-us'). Language version, domain name, display culture name, url prefix are my settings.

Comment: It seems like the place where you need that logic is a controller, not a route.

Comment: To build the most correct url address by calling ItemDisplayUrl that uses everywere I probably should override RouteBase.GetVirtualPath. (that i will get correct url inside one language version).
I can place logic for building url to routeBase and place logic for displaying page by this url to controller. It will work. But it seems to me that this two parts should be placed together.

Answer (score 0):

I copied a bit of code from Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest and this code get valid (not null) work context.

```
using (var wcs = _workContextAccessor.CreateWorkContextScope(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context)))
{
    var workContext = wcs.WorkContext;
```

May be i should not use it? What it actually does?